# Transponer un resultado de una columna a otra en Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla similar a la siguiente: (sólo es un ejemplo para acotar el problema)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito llegar a este resultado en el cual en la columna actual para el concepto **C** tengo el resultado del concepto **B** negativo de la columna anterior. Supongamos que sólo tengo datos hasta **Feb**, en ese caso genero una columna auxiliar que denomino Mar en donde veo impactada esa lógica y Jan tendrá los resultado de **2016**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo podría alcanzar el resultado que busco?

Este es el SQL que yo intenté, pero que no me da los resultados esperados:

```
SELECT year_id, id, concept,
CASE WHEN concept <> 'C' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN month_id = 201701 then value else 0 end) 
                         ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN month_id = 201612 and concept = 'B' then value else 0 end)end as Jan,

CASE WHEN concept <> 'C' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN month_id = 201702 then value else 0 end) 
                         ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN month_id = 201701 and concept = 'B' then value else 0 end)end as Feb,

CASE WHEN concept = 'C' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN month_id = 201701 and concept = 'B' then value else 0 end) else 0 end as Mar
from aux 
group by year_id, id, concept
order by year_id, id, concept;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/OXW79387.

Comment: En realidad, esa consulta no da el resultado que indicas (y esto sin tomar en cuenta las inconsistencias en los nombres de columnas en la consulta). Así que me hace dudar si el planteamiento de la pregunta es correcto. Sería muy conveniente que incluyeras un fiddle o al menos un script completo ([mcve]) que nos ayudara a reproducir el resultado que dices que obtienes. Tratar de reproducir de nuestro lado tus datos usando una imagen solamente no es práctico.

Comment: Hola. No es posible hacer eso. Son datos de la empresa que no podría compartir. Pero más allá de la consulta y de sus inconsistencias. Es claro el problema, o con él también hay alguna inquietud.

Comment: No digo que tengas que usar datos de la empresa. Solo digo que sería práctico que crearas un script funcional a partir de tus datos de ejemplo y que demuestran el resultado que dices que obtienes. Examinando, los datos tal como los tienes, no es posible que la consulta genere el resultado (erróneo) tal cómo lo describes. Y obviamente, la razón es porque en realidad tu mismo no has corrido tu propia consulta usando los datos que tienes en la pregunta. Tu lo corres con los datos de verdad de tu empresa.  Pera hay algo que seguramente se te perdió en la traducción y que invalida tu pregunta.

Comment: Por eso vale la pena que creas un script con datos de ejemplo que tanto tu como nosotros podemos usar para reproducir tu resultado.

Comment: Prestando atención a o que me dice este sería el conjunto de datos con los cuales trabajaría. Intenté replicar el resultado pero no lo consigo

Comment: http://rextester.com/CSEU3104

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que me di cuenta.  Aun así, voy a ver si se puede hacer lo que pides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La siguiente consulta produce el resultado deseado:

```
with cte as (
    select month_id,
           year_id,
           id,
           concept,
           value
      from aux
     where concept in ('A', 'B', 'D')
     union all
    select case when month_id = 12 then 1 else month_id + 1 end as month_id,
           case when month_id = 12 then year_id + 1 else year_id end as year_id,
           id,
           'C' as concept,
           value * -1 as value
      from aux
     where concept = 'B'
)
select id,
       concept,
       year_id,
       coalesce(sum(case when month_id = 1 then value end),0) as jan,
       coalesce(sum(case when month_id = 2 then value end),0) as feb,
       coalesce(sum(case when month_id = 3 then value end),0) as mar
  from cte
 where year_id = 2017 -- escoges el año que quieres aquí
 group by id,
          concept,
          year_id
 order by id,
          concept;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/TYY8344)</kbd>

---

En la consulta, asumo que la columna `month_id` contiene valores de `1` a `12`, en vez de los valores `201612`, `201701`, `201702` que tienes en tu pregunta. Me parece que esto tiene mas sentido que incluir el año en la columna que se supone contiene el mes nada mas.

Como verás, la clave está en el CTE, donde recojo los valores tal cual para los conceptos `A`, `B` y `D`, pero ignoro por completo los registros con el concepto `C`. Mas bien, con la ayuda del `UNION ALL`, genero y agrego registros virtuales de concepto `C` para el mes siguiente que se basan en los valores de los registros del concepto `B`.

Ya con esa consulta intermediaria preparada, es fácil aplicar un `GROUP BY` combinado con `SUM` condicionales por mes.  Y si quieres datos para otro año, solo necesitas cambiar la condición en un lugar, donde está el `WHERE year_id = 2017`.

Comment: Excelente sstan!!. Como siempre mil gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Transponer no se puede hacer con SQL puro porque en un SQL tiene que quedar fijas la cantidad de columas. Se puede hacer con SQL dinámico.

Si supiéramos que las columnas son solo los meses la solución con SQL puro podría ser:

```
select id, concept, year_id
   , sum(case when month_id=10 then value else null end) as "mes_10"
   , sum(case when month_id=11 then value else null end) as "mes_11"
   , sum(case when month_id=12 then value else null end) as "mes_12"
  from los_datos
  group by id, concept, year_id;
```

Se puede ver un ejemplo corriendo en: http://rextester.com/YIIA70954

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Emilio. Voy a revisar la respuesta que se propone. Y voy a tener muy en cuenta la página de la solución para realizar futuras preguntas.

Comment: los renglones de "sum" se podrían generar dinámicamente dentro del programa en base a los month_id esperados...